# MySQL : complex query dynamic select?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I searching for many times now on a complex MySQL query.

It's an achievement system.

Structure of tables is simple and form is symmetric.

The first table (achievements_base) contains the achievements reference : each achievement have :
- an ID (id of the row, auto-increment & unique),
- a code_id (reference of the achievement),
- a rank_id (sub-category of achievement's code_id),
- and the achievement name (display purposes).

The second table (achievements_user) contains the achievements obtained by the users : each achievement unlocked have :
- an ID (if of the row, auto-increment & unique),
- the code_id (reference of the achievement),
- a rank_id (sub-category of achievement's code_id),
- and the user id.

The tables syntax is :

```
achievements_base
id - code_id - rank_id - name
1 - 1 - 1 - foo
2 - 1 - 2 - bar
3 - 1 - 3 - foobar
4 - 1 - 4 - foofoo
5 - 2 - 1 - barbar

achievements_user
id - code_id - rank_id - user_id
1 - 1 - 1 - 1
2 - 1 - 2 - 1
3 - 2 - 1 - 1
```

I want to display achievements that user don't have (GROUP BY code_id)

```
In the table exemple above, for example, expected result is, for the user_id 1 :
3 - 1 - 3 - foobar
```

But I don't see how to do that ! I've already tried multiples queries.

Sorry for my English, I'm French !

Thanks !

edit, example of one of queries that I've tried :

```
SELECT AB.name
FROM achievements_base AB
RIGHT JOIN achievements_users AU 
ON AU.code_id = AB.code_id AND AU.rank_id = AB.rank_id
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM achievements_users AU WHERE AU.user_id = 1) = 0
GROUP BY AB.code_id
ORDER BY AB.code_id ASC
```

Comment: [Show us what you have tried.](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following?

```
SELECT code_id
FROM achievements_base
WHERE code_id NOT IN
( 
   SELECT code_id
   FROM achievements_user
   WHERE user_id = 1
)
GROUP BY code_id
```

Comment: WHERE NOT IN is the good syntax, it's effective ! Big thank you ! ;)

Comment: Check carefully here.. this will check the code_id only, not the combination of code_id and rank_id. I'm not sure if that's acceptable for your purpose. If it is, GREAT! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ab.*
FROM achievements_base ab
LEFT OUTER JOIN achievements_user au 
ON ab.id = au.code_id
WHERE au.user_id = {userid}
```

Untested, and I'm just now learning joins, but an outer join is definitely what you want to go with.

Comment: No sorry outer join is not the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? **EDIT** This should do the trick..

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    achievements_base 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT 
        ab.id 
    FROM
        achievements_base ab 
        RIGHT JOIN achievements_user au 
            ON (
                ab.code_id = au.code_id 
                AND ab.rank_id = au.rank_id
            ) 
    WHERE au.user_id = 1)
```